# ntheorem Endmark On Line Alone Doesn't Flush Right

Tags: enumitem, ntheorem

`ntheorem` seems to successfully handle every possible endmark placement EXCEPT when it's placed on a line alone.

I noticed the issue following a list so I included it in the MWE.

Also I'm relatively new to LaTeX so I couldn't come up with regular text that filled the line AND pushed the endmark to the next one.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath} % requires amsmath
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newlist{examplelist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examplelist]{label=(\alph*), nosep, wide, labelwidth=!, labelindent=0pt}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\sffamily\fontseries{bc}\selectfont\normalsize}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorempreskip{\topsep}
\theorempostskip{\topsep}
\theoremindent0pt
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newtheorem{example}{EXAMPLE}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}

\begin{examplelist}
\item First item would go here.
\item But if there's lots of text in the next item that fills the last line in the theorem, ntheorem correctly places the endmark on the subsequent line, but it's not flush right.
\end{examplelist}

\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

AMS style states:

> The QED box may land flush right on a separate line if it follows a full line of text, a display, or a list. (p.32, October 2017)

This is my first question ever on SE. It's been a huge help to me with so many topics.

Comment: Thanks! Hope I didn't overlook something obvious.

Comment: First of, ntheorem end markers does not like blank lines before the `\end` part of the environment, that tend to break the placement. Not sure if that is the case here. Another issue might be that ntheorem is not hooking code into custom lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I only have a workaround:

```
\begin{examplelist}
\NoEndMark % <==========================================================
\item First item would go here.
\item But if there's lots of text in the next item that fills the last 
line in the theorem, ntheorem correctly places the endmark on the 
subsequent line, but it's not flush right. 

\hfill \exampleSymbol % <===============================================
\end{examplelist}
```

I used `\NoEndMark` to get no automatik end mark. Then -- **important** -- I added one blank line and added the wanted end mark manually with `\hfill \exampleSymbol`.

That is no automatic solution, but you get the end mark at the end of the line and not at the beginning.

With the complete code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath} % requires amsmath

%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newlist{examplelist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examplelist]{label=(\alph*), nosep, wide, labelwidth=!, labelindent=0pt}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\sffamily\fontseries{bc}\selectfont\normalsize}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorempreskip{\topsep}
\theorempostskip{\topsep}
\theoremindent0pt
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newtheorem{example}{EXAMPLE}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}

\begin{examplelist}
\NoEndMark % <==========================================================
\item First item would go here.
\item But if there's lots of text in the next item that fills the last 
line in the theorem, ntheorem correctly places the endmark on the 
subsequent line, but it's not flush right. 

\hfill \exampleSymbol % <===============================================
\end{examplelist}

\end{example}

\end{document}
```

You get the result:

[image]

Comment: Does the trick!  I tried an `\hfill` before the `tikzpicture` that defines my endmark to try an automatic fix, but that didn't work.  I'm accepting your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `\strut` after the list, to create a new blank line, appears to work.  Also note that the examples in the documentation all define the end-of-theorem symbol as something like `\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}`.

If you redefine `\qedsymbol`, which I’d recommend, you can insert a flush-right end-of-proof symbol at the end of any line with `\hfill\qedsymbol`.

In this example, I use my personal favorite variant, `\QED` from the STIX font (as it appears in some editions of DEK’s *The Art of Computer Programming*).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth = 10cm]{geometry} % An appropriate width for a MWE
                                         % on TeX.SX.  Delete this.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{stix}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures = Common]
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Ligatures = Common]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[range=\QED, Scale=MatchUppercase]{XITS Math}

% The “tombstone” QED symbol introduced by Paul Halmos, and used in some
% editions of DEK’s The Art of Computer Programming:
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\QED}}

\newlist{examplelist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examplelist]{label=(\alph*), nosep, wide, labelwidth=!, labelindent=0pt}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\selectfont}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorempreskip{\topsep}
\theorempostskip{\topsep}
\theoremindent 0pt
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\qedsymbol}}
\newtheorem{example}{EXAMPLE}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}

\begin{examplelist}
\item First item would go here.
\item Clear the line:
\end{examplelist}
\strut

\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image: Theorem example]

If you have to, or would rather, use PDFLaTeX, that example will also work if you take out all the `unicode-math` lines and load `stix`.

Comment: In your MWE, according to AMS style, the endmark should be placed on the same line as item (b). `ntheorem` correctly handles that.  When I add `\strut`after the list it makes no difference to the output.  My issue is with a full last line and the endmark on its own line. I am using PDFLaTeX, so I'm not sure if that is impacting this issue or not.

Comment: @Benjamin Remove the `_` and it will no longer be typeset as a subscript, so that should match the style you want. I’ll look at another example.

Comment: In my original document I redefined `\theoremsymbol` as a `tikzpicture`. But since I could recreate the issue with a standard symbol, I posted as such to keep the MWE minimal.

Comment: @Benjamin Sounds great. I’m in the middle of something else, but a good way to fill an entire line exactly, for testing purposes, is to `\usepackage{parskip}` and then end the theorem with `\framebox[\textwidth]{Filling an entire line.\hfill} \\ `. I find that `ntheorem` likes to push the end symbol up *above* the box.